# How to set OpenSearch/Elasticsearch as the destination of a Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create Data Stream -> Firehose -> OpenSearch infrastructure using the AWS CDK v2. I was surprised to find that, although OpenSearch is a supported Firehose destination, there is nothing in the CDK to support this use case.

In my CDK Stack I have created an OpenSearch [`Domain`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_opensearchservice.Domain.html), and am trying to create a Kinesis Firehose [`DeliveryStream`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha.DeliveryStream.html) with that domain as the destination. However, kinesisfirehose-destinations package seems to only have a ready-to-use [destination for S3 buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations-alpha.S3BucketProps.html), so there is no obvious way to do this easily using only the constructs supplied by the aws-cdk, not even using the alpha packages.

I think I should be able to write an OpenSearch destination construct by implementing [`IDestination`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha.IDestination.html). I have tried the following simplistic implementation:

```js
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import * as firehose from "@aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha"
import {aws_opensearchservice as opensearch} from "aws-cdk-lib"

export class OpenSearchDomainDestination implements firehose.IDestination {
  private readonly dest: opensearch.Domain

  constructor(dest: opensearch.Domain) {
    this.dest = dest
  }

  bind(scope: Construct, options: firehose.DestinationBindOptions): firehose.DestinationConfig {
    return {dependables: [this.dest]}
  }
}
```

then I can use it like so,

```js
export class MyStack extends Stack {
  ...
  private createFirehose(input: kinesis.Stream, output: opensearch.Domain) {

    const destination = new OpenSearchDomainDestination(output)
    const deliveryStream = new firehose.DeliveryStream(this, "FirehoseDeliveryStream", {
      destinations:       [destination],
      sourceStream:       input,
    })

    input.grantRead(deliveryStream)
    output.grantWrite(deliveryStream)
  }
}
```

This will compile and `cdk synth` runs just fine. However, I get the following error when running `cdk deploy`:

```
CREATE_FAILED | AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream | ... Resource handler returned message: "Exactly one destination configuration is supported for a Firehose
```

I'm not sure I understand this message but it seems to imply that it will reject outright everything except the one provided S3 bucket destination.

---

So, my titular question could be answered by the answer to either of these two questions:

1. How are you supposed to implement `bind` in `IDestination`?
2. Are there any complete working examples of creating a Firehose to OpenSearch using the non-alpha L1 constructs?

(FYI I have also [asked this question on the AWS forum](https://repost.aws/questions/QUj8QXhYhGS3iZtMi3VkhGSg/cdk-how-to-set-open-search-elasticsearch-as-the-destination-of-a-kinesis-firehose) but have not yet received an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Other destinations (at the moment) than S3 are not supported by the L2 constructs. This is described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-kinesisfirehose-readme.html

In such cases, I go to the source code to see what can be done. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose/lib/destination.ts . There is no easy way how to inject other destination than S3 since the `DestinationConfig` does not support it. You can see at https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations/lib/s3-bucket.ts how the config for S3 is crafted. And you can see how that config is used to translate to L1 construct `CfnDeliveryStream` at https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/f82d96bfed427f8e49910ac7c77004765b2f5f6c/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose/lib/delivery-stream.ts#L364

Probably easiest way at the moment is to write down your L1 constructs to define destination as OpenSearch.